# How to get Windows to recognise external SCSI tape drive?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

We have a HP DL380 G3 with HP LTO3 Ultrium external tape drive attached via VHDCI SCSI port.
How do we get Windows Server 2003 to recognise the tape drive so it can be used?

The tape drive doesn't show up in NT Backup even though it is connected & powered on. The HP driver is installed.

Comment: Does it show up in device manager?  Have you rebooted the server since attaching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting Windows is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It comes with and needs 'HP Data Protector Express Single Server Edition Software', use that.

It's use with NTBackup is specifically discouraged/unsupported.